# High altitude Concentrated Solar Power (CSP)

Tags: energy, renewable-energy

Are there any advantages in terms of energy output and efficiency in installing a high altitude concentrated solar power facility? Hypothetically speaking, what if we could build a facility similar to ‘Ivanpah Solar Power Facility’ but one mile above the ground?

Comment: Do you mean above ground or above sea level?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in available light for capture between sea level and one mile up is too small to justify building the facility on a mountaintop. Instead you'd simply build it at sea level where the living is easy and flat, level real estate is cheap and just add an extra mirror or two.

The only exception would be if one mile up meant you were free from cloud cover, but even then you'd need to know how many extra cloud-free days you'd get on average, and see if that would justify the extra expense.